# What is the meaning of 'cannot resolve symbol R' error in android studio?

Tags: android-studio

When I try to compile my project it says cannot resolve symbol R. why do I get that error? If it's because an xml file is corrupted what is the solution to the above issue?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.advanced_quiz);
}
```

Comment: post a sample of the code where you are getting this error, this will help us better understand what is going on!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens all the time to me as well. Especially when going between versions or basically changing anything with Android Studio.

Without more information, I can't give you a definite answer, but typically cleaning and rebuilding the project fixes these issues for me.

Go to "Build", then "Clean Project." After that, go to "Build", then "Rebuild project."

Let me know if that works. If it doesn't, there are other possible solutions I can add.